# InvalidOperationException no connection string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, connection-string

I'm using LinqToSql for my project's data layer. I set up a data model through the wizard, but I'm getting an InvalidOperationException saying that the connection string doesn't exist.

Here's a screenshot that shows the error and the connection string side-by-side.

[image: InvalidOperationException]

I've done a clean and rebuild of the solution, I've also done several fresh new builds...

I understand what the error means, but as the connection string is there in the App.Config file, I have no idea how to fix it.

Can anyone provide some clarity?

Comment: `App.config` applies to the *application*, not your project.  You've defined your `App.config` in your library project.  Try moving it into one of your front-end projects.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `app.config` file with `connectionStrings` section configured to your `imajManagement` project (startup project)

Comment: Should I move it or copy it?

Comment: Copy it, connection strings in your project are used by `imajPOSDataModel.edmx` Entity Framework Model Browser to connect to database when, for example, you want to validate the model against database(they are not required there though).

Comment: meh now on the same highlighted section on POSUsers, I'm getting a NullReferenceException -_-

Comment: how do you create your `ie` context? is it based on your connection string?

Comment: Actually, this new error is on Form1 in the Management project... the context is just instaciated like so -> `private imajposEntities ie = new imajposEntities();` in the classes where its needed

Comment: what is the signature of your `imajposEntities` constructor?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51282/discussion-between-ortund-and-andrew)

Comment: in your connection string you need to specify fully qualified name for the assembly containing the model...`metadata=res://ImajPOSData, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=KEYKEYKEY/imajposEntities.csdl` and so on